# Is there a way to block WebView2 from launching Windows Network Diagnostics window?

Tags: windows, microsoft-edge, webview2

In my WPF application with WebView2 control, it is required that any interaction (like clicking links) inside the page does not launch any external windows (i.e. any windows that is not part of the application).

In case a page the WebView2 is loading is not accessible or a timeout occurs, ERR_TIMED_OUT page is displayed with a link to run Windows Network Diagnostics as shown below.

[image: ERR_TIMED_OUT]

When clicking "Running Windows Network Diagnostics" link, it launches msdt.exe.

Is there a way to prevent WebView2 from launching other applications and windows like msdt.exe?

Comment: Not a wpf/.net guy but it looks like there is a NavigationCompleted event that allows you to detect if a page fails. If you detect a failure to load you could display your own error screen provided by the app that doesn't have any external links. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2navigationcompletedeventargs?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1210.39

Comment: I agreed with what etchesketch mentioned, if you want to block external links to launch other applications and windows, defining custom response pages would be a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`CoreWebView2.Settings.IsBuiltInErrorPageEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2settings.isbuiltinerrorpageenabled?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1210.39) to disable built in error pages, and then in [`CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.web.webview2.core.corewebview2.navigationcompleted?view=webview2-dotnet-1.0.1210.39) watch for errors and show your own error page.

```cs
private async void InitializeWebView2Async()
{
    await WebView2.EnsureCoreWebView2Async();
    WebView2.CoreWebView2.Settings.IsBuiltInErrorPageEnabled = false;
    WebView2.NavigationCompleted += WebView2_NavigationCompleted;
}

private void WebView2_NavigationCompleted(WebView2 sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
{
    if (!args.IsSuccess)
    {
        sender.NavigateToString("Navigation Failure: " + args.WebErrorStatus);
    }
}
```